# How to create a form using mvc framework in phpmysql?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

Using mvc structure I create the files below it works, but I want to create a simple form and store that data into mysql database and retrieve data from db, where I will write query for db and config db. How to do this, please give me some idea guys...

THIS MY index.php file

```
     <?php 
     include_once('../../../mvc/Controller.php');


     if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])){
       //reads and explodes the querystring into array eg 
       //index.php?Controller/getAllCars
      //where Controller end up in $querArray[0]=Controller 
    // and getAllCars end up in $queryArray[1]=getAllCars
       $queryArray=explode('/',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
       $controller=new $queryArray[0];
       //calls the method in the controller that gets data from the model
       //and assigns it to a view that presents it
       //$controller->getAllCars();

       if(isset($queryArray[2])){
          $controller->$queryArray[1]($queryArray[2]);
       }
       else{
         $controller->$queryArray[1]();
       }
     }
     echo '<a href="./index.php?Controller/getAllCars">Show cars</a>';
     ?>
```

This my controller code:

```
    <?php
    include_once('../../../mvc/Model.php');
    include_once('../../../mvc/View.php');
    class Controller{
      private $model;
       private $view;
      function __construct(){
         $this->model=new Model();
          $this->view =new View();
      }
     public function getAllCars(){

        $cars=$this->model->getCars();


        //assigns data from the model to a variable cars
        //that will be presented in the "html" file
        $this->view->assign('cars',$cars);
        //displays the "html" file that will present data from the model
        $this->view->display('./cars.html');

      }
      public function getCarByRegnumber($regnumber){
         //assigns data from the model to a variable cars
        //that will be presented in the "html" file
        $this->view->assign('car', $this->model->getCarByRegnumber($regnumber));
        //displays the "html" file that will present data from the model
        $this->view->display('./cars.html');

      }
    }//end claSS  

    ?>
```

This my model.php code:

```
    <?php
    class Model {
      private $cars;
     function __construct(){
       $this->cars=array('abc123'=>'volvo','bbb123'=>'bmw','ccc123'=>'audi');//here values for variable assigned
     } 
     public function getCars(){
        return $this->cars;
      }
     public  function  getCarByRegnumber($regnumber){
       return $this->cars[$regnumber];

      }
    }
    ?>
```

this my view.php code:

```
    <?php
    class View {
     private $data=array();
      function assign($varname,$vardata){
         $this->data[$varname]=$vardata;
      }
      function display($filename){
        //extract the data that the controller got from the model
        extract($this->data);
        //include the file that presents the extracted data
        include($filename);
      }

    }


    ?>
```

this my cars.html code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Your page title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <?php
        //loops the data that the controller got from the model and puttedd in th view
          foreach($cars as $key =>$car){
            echo '<li>';
            echo $car;
            echo '</li>';
          }

        ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
```

Comment: I'd say if you implemented all that code you posted here then you certainly will know how to implement a html form too.

Comment: i want to know where i need to write query for inserting and reteriving data from db

Comment: @arkascha please give me a idea where i need to write query and where i will create simple form

Comment: Sorry, don't get that wrong, but... could it be that you have no idea how your own code you posted actually works?

Comment: @ arkascha i have a idea but it does not works so i asked to u ...pls help me i'm a beginer,so i doing like this small tasks to learn mvc..

Comment: Well, the html form obviously belongs into the view or the html template used by the view (where else should html go?) and the processing of the form is initialized by the controller and performed by the model.